# QAOA and symmetry effects on the angles

Tags: quantum-algorithms, qaoa

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01041), QAOA on Maxcut shows symmetries that allow them to restrict their search space intervals. But how do they find such intervals knowing that in the original QAOA angles $\gamma,\beta$ are set on the intervals $[0,2\pi], [0,\pi]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Appendix A of [Sack and Serbyn](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.05742.pdf) gives a fairly straightforward explanation wherein the β may be restricted to [-π/4, π/4] for problems exhibiting a Z2 symmetry, such that a global spin flip does not change the cost evaluation; the γ may be restricted to [-π/2, π/2] for unweighted maxcut instances since there is a redundancy about π, while this restriction may not be applied for the larger class of weighted graphs.

Additionally, page 10 of [this PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.07419.pdf) has a few other nice angle symmetries.